# Indexing 2-Dimentional Matrix (pointer style) - error: cant index

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, indexing

I have a problem with indexing a a 2D matrix declare as pointer. 
Here is what I am doing

```
Compute(int *matrix, int rows, int cols )
{
    int i, j;

    for(j = 1; j < cols; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
              matrix[j][i] = 5;     //what is wrong with this line?
        }
    }
}
```

Error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

Any help?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 2D array pointer should be double pointer array (`**matrix`).In your code matrix is declared as a single dimension (`*matrix`) array in function arguments. It should be `**matrix`

```
Compute(int **matrix, int rows, int cols )
{
    int i, j;

    for(j = 1; j < cols; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
              matrix[j][i] = 5; 
        }
    }
}
```